# URL response is 9422 ms, which exceeds the threshold (8000 ms):unitrl

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal-7

We are getting monitoring alert multiple times.
URL response is 9422 ms, which exceeds the threshold (8000 ms):unitrl
How can we resolve this issue and why alert generate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to resolve this issue

Comment: On StackOverflow every user is required to put at least minimal effort to solving problem on her/his own and show it. Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)